# GREP with multiple exact matches

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have an CSV file which holds information in below format -

```
       V1       V2       V3
   1: ITC 02-01-12  96.4500
   2: ITC 03-01-12  97.5833
   3: ITC 04-01-12  97.0500
```

The Column 'V1' has many names including `'ITC'` also `'A & B'`, `'XXX 40'` etc etc.

Now I want to fetch rows which have pattern like `ITC` in `V1` & `date pattern XX` in `V2` or `A & B` in `V1` & `date pattern XX` in `V2`. Match for `V1` and `V2` should be exact match.

In case if I had only `'ITC'`, I could use below syntax

```
grep -w ITC,[0-9][0-9] file.csv
```

But in the present case, I have 2 items for `V1` i.e. `ITC and 'A & B'`. Any pointer what will be the right `grep syntax` will be highly appreciated

My CSV file is quite big, running in few GBs, so efficient method to fetch such rows will be helpful

Comment: For delimited data, you might want to consider using awk or perl instead

Comment: The fields from the sample file are not separated by commas, but your grep command is looking for 2 subsequent fields separated by a comma. Anyways, taking your unclear and incomplete description at its word, this should do: `grep -E '^(ITC|A & B),[0-9][0-9]-' file`. If you have GNU grep, `grep -P` should be faster.

Comment: Thanks mosvy. This is working. However can you further elaborate what do you mean by 'If you have GNU grep, grep -P should be faster.'? How can I use grep -P syntax?

Comment: `grep -P` will let it use the PCRE engine, which in many cases is faster. The basic syntax is the same as for `grep -E` (`egrep`), and you could just change the `-E` with `-P`.

Comment: With `'grep -P'` I am getting no values whereas `'-E'` is working just fine. I also checked PCRE in my Mac and it is already installed with latest version